# Comparing 2 lists of dictionaries, to find which ones don't appear in both

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionaries that look something like this:

```
list1 =  [{'id' : 1, 'name': 'item1', 'type': 'item'},
          {'id' : 2, 'name': 'item2', 'type': 'item'},
          {'id' : 3, 'name': 'item3', 'type': 'item'},
          {'id' : 1, 'name': 'thing1', 'type': 'thing'}
         ]

list2 = [{'id' : 1, 'name': 'item1', 'type': 'item'},
         {'id' : 2, 'name': 'item2', 'type': 'item'},
         {'id' : 3, 'name': 'item3', 'type': 'item'},
        ]
```

What i want to do is iterate over the lists of dictionaries, and pull out the ones from list1 that are NOT in list2 and have a new list of dictionaries. So my end result should look something like:

```
new_list = [{'id' : 1, 'name': 'thing1', 'type': 'thing'}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a list comp:

```
 [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
 [{'type': 'thing', 'id': 1, 'name': 'thing1'}]
```

dicts that are the have the same content will compare equally

```
In [34]: list1[0] == list2[0]
Out[34]: True
```

You could also use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x: x not in list2,list1)
```